# Use a CTE to traverse to 2nd level in tree

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, tree, common-table-expression

I'm trying to use a CTE to traverse a tree in SQL Server. Ideally what I would like as output is a table which shows for each node in the tree the corresponding node that is second from the top in the tree.

I have some basic code to traverse the tree from a given node, but how can I modify it so it produces the desired output ?

```
DECLARE @temp TABLE 
(
  Id INT
, Name VARCHAR(50)
, Parent INT
)

INSERT @temp 
SELECT 1,' Great GrandFather Thomas Bishop', null UNION ALL
SELECT 2,'Grand Mom Elian Thomas Wilson' , 1 UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 'Dad James Wilson',2 UNION ALL
SELECT 4, 'Uncle Michael Wilson', 2 UNION ALL
SELECT 5, 'Aunt Nancy Manor', 2 UNION ALL
SELECT 6, 'Grand Uncle Michael Bishop', 1 UNION ALL
SELECT 7, 'Brother David James Wilson',3 UNION ALL
SELECT 8, 'Sister Michelle Clark', 3 UNION ALL
SELECT 9, 'Brother Robert James Wilson', 3 UNION ALL
SELECT 10, 'Me Steve James Wilson', 3 

;WITH cte AS 
(
    SELECT Id, Name, Parent, 1 as Depth
    FROM @temp
    WHERE Id = 8
    UNION ALL

    SELECT t2.*, Depth + 1 as 'Depth'
    FROM cte t
    JOIN @temp t2 ON t.Parent = t2.Id
 )
SELECT *
, MAX(Depth) OVER() - Depth + 1 AS InverseDepth
FROM cte
```

As output I would like something like

```
Id      Name                depth2_id  depth2_name
8       Sister Michelle ..  2          Grand Mom Elian ....
7       Brother David ..    2          Grand Mom Elian ....
4       Uncle Michael ..    2          Grand Mom Elian ...
```

Thanks for any tips or pointers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a bit hard to get what your goal, but you can use smth like this:

```
;with cte AS 
(
    select
        t.Id, t.Name, t.Parent, 1 as Depth,
        null as Depth2Parent
    from @temp as t
    where t.Parent is null

    union all

    select
        t.Id, t.Name, t.Parent, c.Depth + 1 as 'Depth',
        isnull(c.Depth2Parent, case when c.Depth = 1 then t.Id end) as Depth2Parent
    from cte as c
        inner join @temp as t on t.Parent = c.Id
)
select *
from cte
```

**<kbd>[sql fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/21047)</kbd>**

Comment: Thanks, that is close to what I want, but I'm still struggling a bit. Basically I have a tree and the top node of the tree is the ancestor to everyone, but I am interested in the ancestor at the 2nd level of the tree. For every possible child node (could be at different levels) I want to find its ancestor at the 2nd level. I don't care too much about the nodes in between, I'm more interested in just the child node and its corresponding ancestor at the second level. Thanks.

Comment: My code does exactly what you want. If you don't want to see top node - you can just filter it out in thefinal select